# mongoose callback results if _id not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was looking for documentation on what arguments mongoose callbacks get if an operation fails due to an object `_id` not being found. I cannot find any. Thus I compared three cases myself. Called with `id` = `'foofoofoofoo'` the following happens:

```
// returns: err = null, obj = null
mySchema.statics.findById = function(id, cb) {
  this.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, cb);
}

// returns: err = null, obj is a cursor with obj.result = { n: 0, ok: 1 }
mySchema.statics.deleteById = function(id, cb) {
  this.remove({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }, cb);
}

// returns: err = null, obj is an Object with obj = { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
mySchema.statics.updateById = function(id, updObj, cb) {
  this.where({ _id: new ObjectId(id) }).update(updObj, cb);
}
```

This imho is a horrible result. I get three completely different types as 2nd argument in the `cb`: a `null`, a cursor and a simple object. Not even the `cursor.result` equals the "simple object" in structure.

My questions are:

1. Am I using some anti pattern / mixed syntax here that leads to such inconsistent results?
2. Where can I find details about what results the mongoose callbacks get called with in different situations?

Comment: I think you can read those links in documentation: 

1) http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html . and 
2) http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Personally always I try to handle the error. :-)

Comment: 1) thanks for your link but in exactly that docs I do not find much specifics on what the callback gets if _id was not found;
2) there is no error in all 3 cases I presented :(

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter `result` in the callback function would be different which depends on the operation. See more details [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html):

> Anywhere a callback is passed to a query in Mongoose, the callback follows the pattern `callback(error, results)`. What `results` is depends on the operation:
>
> - For `findOne()` it is a **potentially-null single document**.
> - `find()` **a list of documents**
> - `count()` **the number of documents**
> - `update()` **the number of documents affected**, etc.
>
> The [API docs for Models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model-js) provide more detail on what is passed to the callbacks.

Hope this help.

Comment: Tank you for the link and quote - unfortunately according to my experiment this is not what is returned, e.g. "update" returns `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` while "remove" returns a cursor. I will upvote this but cannot make it the accepted answer.